# Why doesn't LIMIT=\`ulimit -u\` work in bash?

Tags: bash

In my program I need to know the maximum number of process I can run. So I write a script. It works when I run it in shell but but when in program using `system("./limit.sh")`. I work in bash.
Here is my code:

```
#/bin/bash 
LIMIT=\`ulimit -u\` 

ACTIVE=\`ps -u | wc -l \`

echo $LIMIT > limit.txt

echo $ACTIVE >> limit.txt
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I get a message Illegal option -u

Comment: Instead of using bash, you want to use getrlimit()

Comment: Why do you escape the backticks anyway?

Comment: POSIX `ulimit` has only one option `-f`, Bash provides the `[-SHabcdefilmnpqrstuvxT]` options as extensions to `ulimit`. If you are on a POSIX shell, you are limited to `-f`. (are you sure you are using bash?)

Comment: You shouldn't get `Illegal option -u` from your code as given in the question -- that's the output you'd have *if it didn't have the backslashes*. With backslashes, it causes ```-u`: command not found```, as shown in https://ideone.com/KhufLS (an online interpreter, so we can actually see its behavior in practice).

Comment: BTW, make sure the script has executable permissions -- if it doesn't, the `#!/bin/bash` shebang may not be honored, so it could be getting invoked with `sh` (the shell used by `system()`).

Answer (score 5):

#### Why The Original Fails

Command substitution syntax doesn't work if escaped. When you run:

```
LIMIT=\`ulimit -u\`
```

...what you're doing is running a command named

```
-u`
```

...with the environment variable named LIMIT containing the value

```
`ulimit
```

...and unless you actually *have* a command that starts with `-u` and contains a backtick in its name, this can be expected to fail.

This is because using backticks makes characters which would otherwise be syntax into literals, and running a command with one or more `var=value` pairs preceding it treats those pairs as variables to export in the environment for the duration of that single command.

---

#### Doing It Better

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=$(ulimit -u)
active=$(ps -u | wc -l)
printf '%s\n' "$limit" "$active" >limit.txt
```

- Leave off the backticks.
- Use modern `$()` command substitution syntax.
- Avoid multiple redirections.
- Avoid all-caps names for your own variables (these names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or system; [lowercase names are reserved for application use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)).

---

#### Doing It Right

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >limit.txt   # open limit.txt as output for the rest of the script
ulimit -u         # run ulimit -u, inheriting that FD for output
ps -u | wc -l     # run your pipeline, likewise with output to the existing FD
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on the very first line: `#/bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash` - this is often known as a "shebang" line, for "hash" (#) + "bang" (!)

Without that syntax written correctly, the script is run through the system's default shell, which will see that line as just a comment.

As pointed out in comments, that also means only the standardised options available to the builtin `ulimit` command, which doesn't include `-u`.

Comment: Heh -- I completely missed that; good catch. They'd still be hitting issues elsewhere if the backslashes were there in their literal code, but at this point I'm assuming that they added them as formatting when asking the question and never corrected their error (or answered the people who tried to ask about it).